# How to match meanings array with the words array

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a program that should initialize two String arrays, the first containing 10 words, and the second containing 10 meanings for those words.

The order of the words and meaning should not be the same, they should be shuffled.

Then the program should ask the user for the meaning of each word in the first array one by one, the user should answer with phrases from the second array. When the user answers with a certain phrase, the orderMeanings method should be called.

This method should reorder the meanings as they should be aligned with the indices of words.

let’s say the program asks for the meaning of “Brute” which has index 2 in array 1, the user answers “savage” which is in index 7 in the second array, the program has to swap “savage” with the word at index 2, so that savage becomes at index 2.

After the 10 words are organized, the program should display word from array 1 and its actual meaning from array 2 for all the items in the arrays, each on a separate line.

Problem: I am not sure how to reorder the meanings of the words to match with the actual words

Sample Output:

```
0: confine
1: dire
2: evoke
3: contemplate
4: deception
5: paramount
6: acquisition
7: agitate
8: allude
9: constitute

0: keep something or someone within limits
1: hopeless and dangerous
2: draw forth
3: think deeply about something
4: action of decieving someone
5: Superior
6: act of gaining something
7: to promote something
8: Suggest Indrectly
9: think deeply about something
```

See how every meaning matches the word, and its number? I want that. How would I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class dictionary {

  public static String orderMeanings(String s) {
    String[] meanings = {"suggest indirectly", "keep something or someone within limits", "draw forth", "superior", "act of gaining something", "action of decieving someone", "to form something", "think deeply about something", "to promote something", "hopeless and dangerous"};
    
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] words = {"confine", "dire", "evoke", "contemplate", "deception", "paramount", "acquisition", "agitate", "allude", "constitute"};
    String[] meanings = {"suggest indirectly", "keep something or someone within limits", "draw forth", "superior", "act of gaining something", "action of decieving someone", "to form something", "think deeply about something", "to promote something", "hopeless and dangerous"};
    int i;

    System.out.println("Words: ");
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      System.out.println(i + ": " + words[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("\nMeanings (shuffled): ");
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      System.out.println(i + ": " + meanings[i]);
    }

   System.out.println("\nEnter the meaning of the first word: ");
   String index1 = sc.nextLine();
 
   System.out.println("Enter the meaning of the second word: ");
   String index2 = sc.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Enter the meaning of the third word: ");
   String index3 = sc.nextLine();
  
   System.out.println("Enter the meaning of the fourth word: ");
   String index4 = sc.nextLine();
 
   System.out.println("Enter the meaning of the fifth word: ");
   String index5 = sc.nextLine();
  
   System.out.println("Enter the meaning of the sixth word: ");
   String index6 = sc.nextLine();
 
   System.out.println("Enter the meaning of the seventh word: ");
   String index7 = sc.nextLine();
 
   System.out.println("Enter the meaning of the eighth word: ");
   String index8 = sc.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Enter the meaning of the ninth word: ");
   String index9 = sc.nextLine();
  
   System.out.println("Enter the meaning of the tenth word: ");
   String index10 = sc.nextLine();
   
  }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the sample input array that match your example scenario

Comment: Your code does not yet contain any effort to solve the problem. It only contains code to input data. Have you tried do code to sort the result array? If so, please include the code. If not, possibly you must check out the official Java Tutorial first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to randomize. Essentially what it does is create Lists which are nicer to work with (and also allows you to store the original in the arrays as you did). Then it creates an instance of Random, and picks a random number of iterations for the for loop. Finally, Collections.swap is used to swap two randomly picked elements of the Lists. It's pretty straghtforward, but feel free to lmk with any questions.

```java
        Random r = new Random();
        List<String> w = Arrays.asList(words);
        List<String> m = Arrays.asList(meanings);
        int iterations = r.nextInt(40)+10;
        for(int i=0;i<iterations;i++){
            Collections.swap(m,r.nextInt(10),r.nextInt(10));
            Collections.swap(m,r.nextInt(10),r.nextInt(10));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use a separate array: if you want to reuse the `meanings` array, you must first learn and practice how arrays work. It's not complicate but requires some practice if you're new on arrays. Here's an easy implementation:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class dictionary {

  public static String[] orderMeanings(String s) {
    String[] meanings = {"suggest indirectly", "keep something or someone within limits", "draw forth", "superior", "act of gaining something", "action of decieving someone", "to form something", "think deeply about something", "to promote something", "hopeless and dangerous"};
    return meanings;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] words = {"confine", "dire", "evoke", "contemplate", "deception", "paramount", "acquisition", "agitate", "allude", "constitute"};
    String[] meanings = {"suggest indirectly", "keep something or someone within limits", "draw forth", "superior", "act of gaining something", "action of decieving someone", "to form something", "think deeply about something", "to promote something", "hopeless and dangerous"};
    String[] results = new String[10];
    int i;

    System.out.println("Words: ");
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      System.out.println(i + ": " + words[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("\nMeanings (shuffled): ");
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      System.out.println(i + ": " + meanings[i]);
    }

   System.out.println("\nEnter the meaningss of the first word: ");
   String index1 = sc.nextLine();
   int i1 = Integer.parseInt( index1 );
   results[ 0 ] =  meanings [ i1 ];
 
   System.out.println("Enter the meaningss of the second word: ");
   String index2 = sc.nextLine();
   int i2 = Integer.parseInt( index2 );
   results[ 1 ] =  meanings [ i2 ];

   System.out.println("Enter the meaningss of the third word: ");
   String index3 = sc.nextLine();
   int i3 = Integer.parseInt( index3 );
   results[ 2 ] =  meanings [ i3 ];

   System.out.println("Enter the meaningss of the fourth word: ");
   String index4 = sc.nextLine();
   int i4 = Integer.parseInt( index4 );
   results[ 3 ] =  meanings [ i4 ];

   System.out.println("Enter the meaningss of the fifth word: ");
   String index5 = sc.nextLine();
   int i5 = Integer.parseInt( index5 );
   results[ 4 ] =  meanings [ i5 ];

   System.out.println("Enter the meaningss of the sixth word: ");
   String index6 = sc.nextLine();
   int i6 = Integer.parseInt( index6 );
   results[ 5 ] =  meanings [ i6 ];

   System.out.println("Enter the meaningss of the seventh word: ");
   String index7 = sc.nextLine();
   int i7 = Integer.parseInt( index7 );
   results[ 6 ] =  meanings [ i7 ];

   System.out.println("Enter the meaningss of the eighth word: ");
   String index8 = sc.nextLine();
   int i8 = Integer.parseInt( index8 );
   results[ 7 ] =  meanings [ i8 ];

   System.out.println("Enter the meaningss of the ninth word: ");
   String index9 = sc.nextLine();
   int i9 = Integer.parseInt( index9 );
   results[ 8 ] =  meanings [ i9 ];
 
   System.out.println("Enter the meaningss of the tenth word: ");
   String index10 = sc.nextLine();
   int i10 = Integer.parseInt( index10 );
   results[ 9 ] =  meanings [ i10 ];

   System.out.println("\nResults (sorted): ");
   for( i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ){
       String result = results[i];
       System.out.println( i+": "+result );
   }
   
  }
}
```

The result:

```
$ java dictionary
Words: 
0: confine
1: dire
2: evoke
3: contemplate
4: deception
5: paramount
6: acquisition
7: agitate
8: allude
9: constitute

Meanings (shuffled): 
0: suggest indirectly
1: keep something or someone within limits
2: draw forth
3: superior
4: act of gaining something
5: action of decieving someone
6: to form something
7: think deeply about something
8: to promote something
9: hopeless and dangerous

Enter the meaningss of the first word: 
1
Enter the meaningss of the second word: 
9
Enter the meaningss of the third word: 
2
Enter the meaningss of the fourth word: 
7
Enter the meaningss of the fifth word: 
5
Enter the meaningss of the sixth word: 
3
Enter the meaningss of the seventh word: 
4
Enter the meaningss of the eighth word: 
8
Enter the meaningss of the ninth word: 
0
Enter the meaningss of the tenth word: 
7

Results (sorted): 
0: keep something or someone within limits
1: hopeless and dangerous
2: draw forth
3: think deeply about something
4: action of decieving someone
5: superior
6: act of gaining something
7: to promote something
8: suggest indirectly
9: think deeply about something
```